# ValueError: time data does not match format, optional milliseconds

Tags: python, datetime

I have a hacky solution but it feels completely wrong.  I'm simply doing a compare of dates (one starts as a string which I convert) and my `start_date` *sometimes* contains milliseconds.  I was running this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def main():

    start_date = "2019-05-22 20:00:02.1231"

    try:
        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        print("i have milliseconds")
    except:
        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print("no milliseconds")

    if start_date < datetime.now():
        print("yipee")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There is also a chance that there are no seconds, so I could have:

`start_date = "2019-05-22 20:00"`

I could add another `try` but I think I'm just missing a simple solution.  I found this: [python strptime format with optional bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584364/python-strptime-format-with-optional-bits) which suggests use `try` so I would use `try` twice in this case, so is that the answer?

Comment: Yes, that's the answer.

Comment: So just use `try` twice.  Okie dokie, I was hoping there was some super duper clever :)

Comment: Also related: [Parsing Timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48408946/parsing-timestamp-in-python/48409213#48409213)

Comment: There's also the `dateutil` library: [Convert “unknown format” strings to datetime objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258554/convert-unknown-format-strings-to-datetime-objects) or you *could* use regular expressions.